# Permutations in a necklace with repeated beads

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A string of beads is made up of 5 oranges and 5 black beads. If they are randomly arranged around the necklace, how many possible combinations are there?

My understanding:

Permutations in closed loop without repeated beads would be $\frac{9!}{2!}$. To find the permutations with
the repeated colors, I divided by $5!5!$ to get $\frac{9!}{2!5!5!}=12.5$.

The answer given is 63. Does anyone know where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *count* of arrangements cannot be anything but an integer. To get the correct count of necklaces use Burnside's lemma with group $C_{10}$:

- $\binom{10}5=252$ necklaces invariant under identity
- $0$ necklaces invariant under $1/10,3/10,7/10,9/10$ of a turn
- $2$ necklaces invariant under $1/5,2/5,3/5,4/5$ of a turn (alternate the colours)
- $0$ necklaces invariant under $1/2$ of a turn (this would imply that opposite beads are the same colour, hence there are an even number of beads of any colour, which is not the case)

Hence there are $\frac{252+4\cdot2}{10}=26$ possible necklaces; $63$ is also wrong.